# how can i setup auto send email to me when click the <a href> link

Tags: javascript, html

```js
    function sendMail() {
    var link = "mailto:myemail@testemail.com.hk"
             + "&subject=" + escape("This is my subject")
             + "&body=" + escape("This is my body")
    ;

    window.location.href = link;   }
```

```html
<a href="www.google.com" target="_self" onclick="sendMail(); return false">Link</a>
```

i had try the above code, but when i click the link, it just can send email, but the page is not go to www.google.com website, how can i let it run together? many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one thing you could do is change which page it's run on - open the `mailto` link in a new tab, and open `www.google.com` in the current tab:

```js
function sendMail() {
    var link = "mailto:myemail@testemail.com.hk"
         + "&subject=" + escape("This is my subject")
         + "&body=" + escape("This is my body");
    window.open(link, "_blank");   
}
```

```html
<a href="www.google.com" target="_self" onclick="sendMail(); return false">Link</a>
```

Comment: No problem @REFNOWE, always glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
function sendMail() {
  window.location.href = "mailto:abc@example.com?subject=This is my subject&body=This is my body";
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = "https://Google.com";
  })
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sendMail()"> Link </button>
```

Comment: i had try it, and when i click the button, the page can go to google.com, but no email can let me send. any way, i fixed my problem via Jack Bashford, thank you for your reply^^.